# while (var != var)

Tags: java

while (var != var)
    System.out.println(" loop.. ");

execute it..
how to declare..var

Comment: Its tagged homework now, hence why I've tried to help.

Comment: Is it forbidden to post homework questions here? I agree with the tag, but why the -1 then?

Comment: Sounds like a Java Puzzler. I suggest, read the book or find the stackoverflow question that already deals with this.

Comment: Because you only learn by trying for yourself.

Comment: I'll upvote this question if there is an answer...

Comment: @Thilo: there is an answer: 'this is not possible' :-p (Although it doesn't seem to be correct afterwards :p))

Comment: @Fortega, @Thilo: there is an answer, and it's been posted

Comment: MISTAKE..
its for my Interview Preparation. Buddies

Comment: And that's the sort of question you're expecting? Unless you're going for a job writing numerical code, a question like that would be a reason to reject a company. And if you are going for a numerical job, well, don't get your hopes too high.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double var = Double.NaN;
    System.out.println("var : " + var);
    while (var != var) {
        System.out.println(" I am inside loop now! ");
    }

}
```

Comment: -1 for providing homework answers

Comment: Tell me, leppie - what does the student learn by trying to find the answer to this on their own?  I'll tell you what... nothing, since this is the *only* edge case to which that question applies.  

Otherwise, I would generally agree with not answering homework questions, but pointing the student in the general direction of the answer.

Comment: If this is indeed a homework question, I see no problem in answering it here given its non-existing educational value.

Comment: He'd learn to google "how to declare" and "java" and re-use his newly acquired google-fu in the future for other topics. No need for downvoting though; I think everyone should decide for themselve whether they gonna answer or not.

Answer (score 21):

Assuming that this is homework, I'll give you a hint, not the answer. You need to define `var` like this:

```
double var = // time for you to understand floating point
```

---

Edit: to make this answer more generally useful, here's [Wikipedia's entry on special floating-point values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Special_values).

Comment: I guess everyone makes that mistake at least once in their career  :)

Comment: For me it was a SQL statement, but yeah, same idea :-)

Comment: seems like one of those dumb tricking questions only a smart arse lecturer would ask and hardly seems fair to me.

Comment: It depends on the context, I suppose. If you're learning loops, then I agree, it's an idiotic trick. If you're writing numerical methods, then there are a whole lot of things about IEEE numbers that you need to know, and this is just one of them. And as I mentioned above, in SQL NULL <> NULL.

Comment: It's somewhat depressing that this is now my top-voted answer.

Comment: There's also volatile var -- but then you'd have a tight timing constraint to get inside the loop

Answer (score 4):

double var = Double.NaN

Comment: Did you try this? `Double.NaN != Double.NaN` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: lol. You say -1 but you don't give -1...

Comment: Not just a homework answer, but a wrong one as well.

Comment: no extrapolated from c#, could be that java does it differently, its a pretty rubbish homework question if its homework imho

Comment: `Double.NaN != Double.NaN == true` on JRE 1.6 at least

Comment: Andrew: That's right, but if you declare "Double var = Double.NaN;" as the original answer suggested, then "var != var" is false. I leave it as an exercise to you to find out why :)

Comment: @jarnbjo - it was `double` rather than `Double` by the time I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, the following will result in an indefinite loop, rather than an infinite loop; but if there was more stuff going on in the main while loop, [I reckon] this could tip-over to be effectively infinite; thought it was worth posting as this is the type of thing that can happen on App Servers in real-life:

```
public class Puzzle extends Thread {
static boolean keepRunning=true;
static int var=0;



public void run() {

while (keepRunning) {
        var++;
}   

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Puzzle p=new Puzzle();
    p.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    p.start();
    System.out.println("Background Thread started");
    try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch(Exception e) { ; } // Dirty hack to give the background thread chance to start :)
    while (var != var) {
        System.out.println(" I am inside loop now! ");
    }

    keepRunning=false; // we escaped from the loop, switch off the background thread.
}

}
```

Comment: actually I think I was wrong about this being able to go 'effectively infinite', but certaintly it is indefinite. (var!=var is sometimes true, due to lack of any synchronization).